# Is it possible to assign equal probabilities to individuals and groups of individuals?

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithms

A popular music festival with a fixed number of available tickets uses a system (algorithm?) that randomly picks from a group of registered individuals who is able to purchase a ticket. The group of registered individuals is considerably larger than the number of available tickets. Nothing confusing so far.

However, the festival organization provides the possibility for registered individuals to become part of a group (up to 20 individuals). The idea is that the system either picks everybody or nobody from a group. The festival organization claims that the probability of being picked by the system is equal for individuals and for groups. I wonder whether this is possible or not?

Comment: Consider a simple case in which there are four tickets for six people. If these people are not in group, they each have a probability of $\frac{4}{6} = \frac{2}{3}$ of being selected. Now put them together in groups of two. We can select two groups to assign the tickets, with every group having a probability of $\frac{2}{3}$ of being selected. Can you see how this applies to larger groups as well?

Comment: @jvdhooft What if you have a single person, a group of 2 and a group of 3 with 4 tickets? Then either the single and the double go, or the single and the triple go.  The single is sure to get a ticket. Nobody else is.

Comment: @jvdhooft Thx, I see how that applies to larger groups as well. I think an important assumption here is that the system views a group as an individual?

Comment: @paw88789 I assumed a fixed group size, but upon reading the question again ("the possibility to become part of a group") you are right that it does not apply when variable group sizes are allowed.

Comment: @QuintenZuurbier The important part is that variable group sizes are possible, which, as paw88789 pointed out above, can result in some individuals having a higher probability of getting a ticket than others.

Comment: It is intuitively obvious to me that the following algorithm will ensure to a very close approximation the same probability to individuals within groups as to individuals themselves: randomly permute the groups, and then take groups "from the top" until you have fewer than 20 tickets left. Distribute the remaining 20 tickets arbitrarily. However, I can't quite figure out the proof of this.

Comment: @QuintenZuurbier In any case, you can't necessarily expect exact equality of probability.  Though depending on the numbers you may be able to get good approximations.  Presumably there would be good approximations if the group sizes are very small compared to the total capacity of the event.

Comment: @paw88789 Ok, seen as the total capacity of the event lies around 10.000 visitors and groups can include up to 20 people, I assume the approximations of probabilities are close to equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if groups are counted as an individual. So if the system forms a list: `person1, person2, ..., personN, group1, group2, ..., groupM` and then chooses randomly from the list until all the tickets are gone. If the number of available tickets is way larger than 20, the probability to be picked either as an individual or a group member are practically the same.

Comment: I agree with this answer but think it could be improved with an explicit bound (based on the total number of tickets), and a proof of that bound.